# conda 32-bit keep installing 64-bit python 3.5.2

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, conda

I installed both 32-bit conda and 64-bit conda for different projects. I created a new environment and specified python 3 in

`conda create -name ..name.. python=3`

The command picked up Python 3.5.2 but in 64-bit, rather than 32. But when I changed the command to

`conda create -name ..name.. python=3.4`

it picked up the 32-bit python correctly. My question is how to force conda to pickup 32-bit python 3.5.2? so I can use some of the packages that only support python 3.5.

Here's what I did and none of them work:

- installed both 32-bit and 64-bit pythons
- installed both 32-bit and 64-bit condas
- set 32-bit Miniconda to come before 64-bit Miniconda in PATH
- launched 32-bit conda prompt
- set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have to delete the package caches first. Or force conda to install Python with -f option.